# Can I connect esp32 to firebase?

Tags: firebase, arduino-esp32

I'm doing simple home security Iot project in which I want to connect esp32 camera module CamWebServer example to firebase Database, and then connect to Android app. Or at least I want to give a link in the app.
I want to give it a remote access. Plus I don't want esp32 cam to depend on home Wi-Fi, I want to depend it on Hotspot module(Is there any type of module available? If it is then please tell me), So it can have it's own internet like mobile has mobile data. 
For example if intruder breaks electricity of home, esp32 cam still be accessed.
Can I do that?
Any type of help is welcomed!!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question isn't a really good fit for StackOverflow as it would be considered off-topic and better suits a forum. You can use the ESP32 with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest) and there are a number of ["ESP32 Firestore"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ESP32+Firestore) projects out there in various stages of development. Communicating over mobile would require something like a [ESP32 SIM800L](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-sim800l-publish-data-to-cloud/).

Comment: Yeah! but I only knew StackOverflow. Thanks for the help!!